# How can I get multiple values from array within array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[meta_data] => Array
   [0] => Array
      (
         [id] => 100
         [name] => John
      )
   [1] => Array
      (
         [id] => 200
         [name] => Peter
      )
   [2] => Array
      (
         [id] => 300
         [name] => Peter
      )
```

What would be the simplest way to select all names from $meta_data?

Thanks.

Comment: That would be [`array-column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

```
var_dump(array_column($array['meta_data'], 'name'));
```